# Why does TCPsocket work in ruby 1.8.7

Tags: ruby, tcpsocket

Run this code

```
rvm 1.8.7,1.9.3-p547 do ruby -r socket -e "puts TCPSocket == TCPsocket"
```

Why on ruby 1.8.7 does this come back as true?

Answer (score 5):

A bit of source archeology shows that [originally the class was named `TCPsocket`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/3db12e8b236ac8f88db8eb4690d10e4a3b8dbcd4/ext/socket/socket.c#L1220) (with a lower case `s`). Later it was [renamed to `TCPSocket`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/0a64817fb80016030c03518fb9459f63c11605ea#diff-854587c698174dc9cdf508b3bae5eb28R1860) (upper case `s`), but a constant was set up with the old name. This was the case in Ruby 1.8.7, so for that version `TCPsocket` and `TCPSocket` referred to the same class and so would compare as equal.

Later still the [original name was removed](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/5a712cfb8ce6947dfc5bcd8b7f27153dd576e13a), leaving only `TCPSocket`. This is the case from 1.9 onwards, so in recent versions using `TCPsocket` will result in a `uninitialized constant` error.

As for why, I guess that Matz originally used `TCPsocket` and later realised that `TCPSocket` was a better name, but left the old name available for a while for compatibility.

Comment: You sir would make Dr. Jones proud! Thank you